# How to use constructed formula with glm.mids

Tags: r, formula, glm, r-mice

Working with a large number of variables and addressing them with constructed formula (via `paste0()`) using variables passed to functions. I have stumbled across a problem/bug I cannot figure out. Easiest explained with a toy example:

```
library(mice)
imp2 = mice(nhanes)

# So both these models run fine:
mod1 <- glm(bmi ~ hyp + age, data=nhanes)
mod1.im <- with(imp2, glm(bmi ~ hyp + age))

# However if I try to pass a formula to glm() in the with() I get an error
formula = bmi ~ hyp + age
mod2 <- glm(formula, data=nhanes)
mod2 <- with(imp2, glm(formula))

#Running the above leads to the following error:
> mod2 <- with(imp2, glm(formula))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'bmi' not found
```

How can I work around this? Why is it not finding BMI ?

Comment: does this provide a work around  that suits your workflow.. `formula <- expression(glm(bmi ~ hyp + age)); mod2 <- with(imp2, formula)`. (Maybe having  a look at `mice:::with.mids` to get some hints.)

Comment: Hi user - thanks but doens't work. My formula is made up like so `varname <- "hyp" ; formula = paste0("bmi ~ ", varname, " + age)` then I run the glm. Can you make your suggestion work with this set-up ?

Comment: you could try `form <- "bmi ~ hyp + age" ; mod2 <- with(imp2, glm(formula(form)))`

Comment: Hi yes that works! I did have another problem but got around that. Thank you! If you put it as an answer I will accept it. (I do think there is some underlying problem here though maybe ?)

Comment: yes, (i think) the problem is in what scope the formulas are generated. Looking at with.mids code, it uses a lot of environment and eval calls, so getting the right scope is a bit tricky. (Hence, why your first code didn't work as you specified the formula in the global environment, where as if you create it as a string and then create the formula in the with.mids scope it seems okay). You might attract more attention from experienced R users if you asked a new, more general question asking for an explanation of the environment / scope issues with this, rather than how to do it.

Comment: The problem is not `with.mids` but how `glm` searches for the variables in `formula` in the absence of `data`. The documentation states: "If not found in ‘data’, the variables are taken from ‘environment(formula)’". For that reason something like `with(df,glm(a~b))` would work, but `fml<-a~b; with(df,glm(fml))` would not. The difference between the two is the environment of the formula, which is local in the first case and global in the second ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804854/r-evaluate-an-expression-in-a-data-frame-with-arguments-that-are-passed-as-an-o)).