# Evaluate model matrix with data passed using function with

Tags: r

Any insights as to why only the first of the two "with" calls below return the model matrix, while the second one returns an error message?

```
data<-data.frame(y=runif(10),x=runif(10))
formula1<-y~x
with(data,model.matrix(y~x))
with(data,model.matrix(formula1))
#Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works

```
data<-data.frame(y=runif(10),x=runif(10))
formula1<-"y~x"
with(data,model.matrix(y~x))
with(data,model.matrix(formula(formula1)))
```

please read [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804854/r-evaluate-an-expression-in-a-data-frame-with-arguments-that-are-passed-as-an-o) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358402/how-to-use-constructed-formula-with-glm-mids?noredirect=1&lq=1) for very similar questions and very insightful comments.